# How to use the validate() grails method without saving?

Tags: grails, persistence, validation

I have a problem with the validate() grails method, when I use entity.validate() the entity object is persisted on the database, but I require validate multiple objects before to save the data.

```
def myAction = {
  def e1 = new Entity(params)
  def ne1 = new EntityTwo(params)

  // Here is the problem
  // If e1 is valid and ne1 is invalid, the e1 object is persisted on the DataBase
  // then I need that none object has saved, but it ocurred. Only if both are success 
  // the transaction should be tried
  if(e1.validate() && ne1.validate()){
    e1.save()
    ne1.save()
    def entCombine = new EntityCombined()
    entCombine.entity = e1
    entCombine.entityTwo = ne1
    entCombine.save()
  }
}
```

My problem is that I do not want the objects to be saved before both validations are successful.

Answer (score 4):

Call discard() on any instance don't want to be automatically persisted when it's detected as changed/dirty:

```
if (e1.validate() && ne1.validate()){
   ...
}
else {
   e1.discard()
   ne1.discard()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not work as I expected, I use grails 1.3.6, please if you have another suggestion.

Comment: if the described solution does not work, you can try to use command objects for validation your values before saving. in your case the command object would look like the same as your domain class. after successful validation you can "copy" the command object into your desired domain class and save it. see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.1.10 Command Objects

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with withTransaction() method, because the discard() method is applied only to update cases.

```
def e1 = new Entity(params)
def ne1 = new EntityTwo(params)

Entity.withTransaction { status ->  
  if(e1.validate() && ne1.validate()){
    e1.save()
    ne1.save()
    def entCombine = new EntityCombined()
    entCombine.entity = e1
    entCombine.entityTwo = ne1
    entCombine.save()
  }else{
    status.setRollbackOnly()
  }
}
```

So the transaction is completed only if the validation is successfully, by other way the transaction is rolled back.

I wait that this info can be to help for any people.
Regards to all! :) YPRA